# How to set custom paper size DocPrintJob in Java?

Tags: java, printing, size, set

I am working on project, which is used to generate and print the labels. I just want to set the custom page width and height (Page width is higher than page height). Can you please guide me how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: well, what have you tried? (Code snippet please, thanks)

Comment: I have followed this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/PrintanImagetoprintdirectly.htm

Comment: Hi, and welcome, Arun M. Don't use greetings and signatures. Your Icon below the post is your sig. Edit your profile, if you like to. Improve your question in the question body, not in the comments. Thanks and welcome.